# How to set "Value" of a "Key" of JSON data in SQLite3

Tags: json, python-2.7, sqlite

Table of SQLite3 contains 2 column  and select command will give below json output :

```
SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1='1';
```

OUTPUT:

> {     "categories": null,     "settings": {       "A": "10",      "B": {          "C":
>   ["Test1","Test2","Test3"]},       "D": "1.0"  } }

Now i wanted to set Value of Key "C" to ["Apple","orange"] .

SQLite3 supports JSON where we can set the value of Key using json_set. But i am not able to do that and need some help on it

Thanks

Comment: Did you [enable loadable extensions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#f1) yet? Out of the box, Python usually does *not* enable this feature.

Comment: Python 2.7 does not have SQLite 3.9.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : "SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION" is not present in Setup.py